# Cannot have htaccess rewrite where the url contains subdirectory with an equal char

Tags: .htaccess, parameters, url-rewriting

I have a url https://example.com/dir/sub=dir/subsubdir 
I want it to be redirected to https://example.com/dir/subdir/subsubdir using htaccess

in other words remove the = char.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

you can use a 301 redirect like so:

```
Redirect 301 /dir/sub=dir/subsubdir https://example.com/dir/subdir/subsubdir
```